# Summation of series of variable degrees...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know it it's a proper question but still as it is troubling me a lot now therefore I am posting this doubt.

**Question**: how to find sum of

$$Z= \sum (r)^t      $$ 
 (from r=1 to  r=n(any natural number))
Where t is a constant for any particular series.
For e.g. for$$ t=1  => Z =n(n+1)÷2.$$
**my approach:** I know how it can be done for t=1,2,3 by considering identity
$$r^{t+1} -(r-1)^{t+1}=......$$//simplification

But this method is too lengthy to be able to use it for higher value of t. I came across a way while surfing on net that required Bernoulli numbers and some other alien things(for me)...which was far to be proved as helpful.

**problem:** but for higher value of t it becomes sisyphean task.
So I require a simple, elegant, universal and effective method.

Comment: Are you looking for a formula for $\sum_{k=m}^{n}r^{k}$?

Comment: I need $$\sum r^k$$ ....where k is constant for a particular sum say its a and only r is running from 1 to n(any number). For e.g. for k= 4 it looks like=$1^4+2^4+3^4........$so on.

Comment: Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula?

Comment: Yes that seems exact solution but a bit more assistance is required.

Comment: What else do you need assistance with?

Comment: Many things there are new to me...so it will be helpful if somebody can provide quick elaboration through his answer...nevertheless It will be still fine otherwise.